# How to Select rows with same value from different table

Tags: sql, sql-server

i am new in sql but not good with the round-abouts of sql codes and scripts

im trying to select bill_no from transactions with the same ref_no that is in the ledger (ref_no is the same as bill_no)

i tried using the following sql code:

```
    SELECT account_no ,bill_no, bill_date,bill_amount FROM 
    TRANSACTIONS_HISTORY
    WHERE bill_no IN 
    (SELECT ref_no FROM LEDGER
    WHERE ledger_code = '002')
```

but i always got the error "Arithmetic overflow error converting nvarchar to data type numeric."

*sorry for wrong format, this is my first time posting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`bill_no` and `ref_no` do not have the same data type.

[You can convert to a different type by using the `CAST` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql). For example:

```
SELECT CAST(ref_no AS INT)
```